# Force ARM GCC to BL directly to address

Tags: c, gcc, thumb

I'm using GCC to compile some Thumb code.
In my linker script, I have my function set up like:
`foo = ABSOLUTE(0xc026cc9c);`
And in my C file, I have:
`foo(50);`

This generates something like this:

```
mov r0, #50
bl foo

foo: .long 0xc026cc9c
```

I want it to generate this:

```
mov r0, #50
bl 0xc026cc9c
```

I can do it in inline assembler, but is is possible for GCC to generate this?

Edit: my gcc flags:  `-std=c99 -c -mthumb -nostartfiles -nostdlib`

Comment: Play with optimization settings.

Comment: I've tried a ton of them and no luck so far. Any other pointers?

Comment: Well, it is a link time constant. That is when compiling, the compiler does not know the address, it only knows the symbol `foo`. The symbol is then resolved when linking and probably cannot be embedded in the code itself.

Comment: Look at the final output of your elf/exe file and dump the function.  Betcha the linker has fixed it up for you.

Comment: have you looked at the gcc sources, I cant imagine why it would generate a bl without a label...there is no use case.  Examine all the cases where it generates a bl and see if any of them do what you want and then see what the switch variables are wrapped around that bl.

Comment: gcc is at compile time not link time so addresses are not known go gcc unless you generate a function pointer then assign that an address, but it is most likely that gcc will generate a mov/add lr,pc and a bx rather than a bl.

Comment: since gcc doesnt know what the address of the bl would be it cannot generate the instruction and it isnt going to insert an instruction that cannot be resolved in the space of one instruction it is going to generate code that wont generate an assembler or linker error (so it cant generate a bl).  but you can still go look.  extremly unlikely that the linker will generate this bl either.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found a workaround.